# Filtering Table Using Json in Angular js

Tags: json, angularjs, parsing, filter, filtering

i would like to ask if it is possible to put a filter in this simple table code using Json in angular form? I am new in Angular and Json. Hope someone can get me out of this problem. the filter will base on the Event,Like if you select the Name John Drake , it will remove the names left. and it will show up the match names as you select and the following description in the selected name like account place and activity in a table , Any suggestion guis? hope someone can help me figure out,my 1 week trial and error.

table.html

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myTable">
<head>
    <title>project  43</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-rc.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myTable=angular.module('myTable',[]);
    myTable.controller('tableCtrl',function($scope,$http){
        $http.get("Table.json").success(function(response) {
        debugger
        $scope.members=response.events;
         $scope.totals = response.paging;
    });

    });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="tableCtrl">

  <th colspan="7" style="text-align:right">         
    <i class="fa fa-search">search   <select ng-model="searchObj.Table" ng-options="item.Table as item.Event for item in filtertable">  <option value="">--Select--</option> </select> </i></th>    

<table id="filtertable"border="5">
   <tr>
    <th>Event</th>
     <th>Account Shop</th>
     <th>Place</th>
     <th>Activity</th>
   </tr>

    <tr ng-repeat="member in members">
    <td>

    {{member.Event.name}}<br>
    {{member.Event.id}}<br>
    {{member.Event.date_start}}<br>
    {{member.Event.date_end}}<br>


    <td>
    {{member.AccountShop.id}}<br>
    {{member.AccountShop.name}}<br>
    {{member.AccountShop.short_code}}<br>
    </td>

    <td >
    <div ng-repeat="Place in member.Place">
    {{Place.id}}<br>
    {{Place.name}}<br>
    {{Place.lk_country_code}}<br>
    </div>
    </td>

    <td>
    <div ng-repeat="Activity in member.Activity">
    {{Activity.id}}<br>
    {{Activity.short_description}}
    </div>

    </td>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Table.json

```
 {
    "events": [
        {
            "Event": {
                "name": "John Drake",
                "id": "59",
                "date_start": "Start 2007-07-06 ",
                "date_end": "End 2007-07-08 "
            },
            "AccountShop": {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "Bike Pte",
                "short_code": "GILL"
            },
            "Place": [
                {
                    "id": "537",
                    "name": "Was",
                    "lk_country_code": "MY"
                }
            ],
            "Activity": [
                {
                    "id": "5671",
                    "short_description": "Bike\r\n"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Event": {
                "name": "Paul Smith",
                "id": "60",
                "date_start": "Start2007-07-13",
                "date_end": "Start 2007-07-15 "
            },
            "AccountShop": {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "Run Pte",
                "short_code": "GILL"
            },
            "Place": [
                {
                    "id": "537",
                    "name": "Cal",
                    "lk_country_code": "MY"
                }
            ],
            "Activity": [
                {
                    "id": "234",
                    "short_description": "Run\r\n"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Event": {
                "id": "61",
                "name": "Thomas Dale",
                "date_start": "Start 2007-07-20 ",
                "date_end": "End 2007-07-22 "
            },
            "AccountShop": {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "Dive Pte",
                "short_code": "JILE"
            },
            "Place": [
                {
                    "id": "47",
                    "name": "Hou",
                    "lk_country_code": "MA"
                }
            ],
            "Activity": [
                {
                    "id": "123",
                    "short_description": "Dive\r\n"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With an input type text :

```
<input type="text" name="nom" ng-model="search.Event.name" />
```

And in u're ng-repeat

```
<tr ng-repeat="member in members | filter:search track by $index ">
```

don't forget the `track by $index` when u're filtering or ordering.

Comment: thankyou ,track by index be like? ,, the project tackles even filtering the Start date and end Date and the name under the event in my table ,

Comment: You can use "$index", it will assign an index to each line.
If you want to search the date you can add/change you're ng-model on the right propertie "search.Event.date_start"

Comment: thank you so much @alexis it works , i thought its a long coding,, last question men , how can i add multiple model to add some Search under event like start date on the right property, tnx! answered prayer .!

Comment: You can insert other input with the ng-model="search.Event.yourproperty".
The filter:search look all ng-model "search.xxxx". if you want a filter on all property you can use search.$ or search.Event.$

Comment: orayt i got it men , thanks! , finally it works ,! answerED

Comment: hi men ,  i finished all the codes and putting filter , i added some model like start date and end date , the code is working , but if youll going to search in names, yes it works but if you'll going to search in dates it can't, but if you refresh it then youll search for date , it is working then if you search in names it wont work ,,vice versa ,do you know whats the problem in that?